# Magento 2 preference not working in di.xml

Tags: magento2, extensions, overrides, dependency

I have a custom module where I'd like to extend the Base Handler

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base" type="Custom\Foo\Handler\DefaultHandler" />
```

Strangewise this does not work in this specifc case, while other preferences are working fine like

```
<preference for="Psr\Log\LoggerInterface" type="Custom\BarFoo\Handler\BaseLog" />
```

Thanks for clarification

Best

Comment: Any debug information? How do you know that it doesn't work?

Comment: facing same issue. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Using this blog post as a walk through on creating a preference:

http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2016/01/22/preferences-in-magento-2/

I walked through the process of creating a preference for the class you are trying to override `Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base` and it worked like a charm. So there is no structural issue with creating a preference for Base.php.

Given that your other preference is working fine, we can assume that your module is working fine, so the next guess would be that the class you are using isn't correct or there is a typo in there. For my test, I used this:

```
<?php

namespace {vender_namespace}\{module_name}\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base;

class Log extends Base {

}
```

And then created a Demo.php file in the root of my Magento install to test that it is working (per the blog post that I linked to)

```
<?php

require_once 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$sample = $bootstrap->getObjectManager()->create('Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base');

\Zend_Debug::dump(get_class($sample));
```

If the returned value is your class, then you know that the preference is working correctly and there is an issue somewhere else in the code.

Comment: i have run this script but it's give me error.what is the issue in prefrence?